# "Completely Reload" Vue/Nuxt Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

**I know how `this.$forceUpdate()` work and not trying to just re-render the component.**

In Nuxt apps, page components have `asyncData()` as their lifecycle methods, executed before `created()`. I'm using it to fetch some initial data and SSR them.

The reason I want to reload the component is to fetch the data again after modifying the corresponding data inside the component, using AJAX. I've tried `this.$forceUpdate()` just in case but didn't work. `this.$router.replace(this.$route.path)` also didn't work. I'm trying to not use `location.reload()` since I have a toast message should be shown after the modification.

Is there any way to do this? Or should I move my fetching part to `fetch()` and call `this.$fetch()`?

Answer (score 1):

I think that Nuxt 3 has a way to do just that which is **refreshNuxtData**.
the docs says :

> refreshNuxtData re-fetches all data from the server and updates the page as well as invalidates the cache of useAsyncData , useLazyAsyncData, useFetch and useLazyFetch.

Answer (score 0):

`this.$nuxt.reload()` was the thing. Not sure if it exists in Vue itself.